# Not able to locate and select the dropdown value in AngularJs using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

[Screenshot added for the element locator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Vgk.png)

I have tried below ways but didn't work out.

```
 element(by.css('option', 'APPLE')).click();
 element(by.xpath("//select[contains(@ng-reflect-model,'Apple')]")).click();
```

Comment: The code and the screenshot that are added are very minimal to find the issue.

Comment: could you try at first click on drop-down element and only then click on option

Answer (score 0):

There are several approach can select the option:

```
1)
element(by.cssContainingText('select[formcontrolname="brandName"] > option', 'APPLE')).click();

2)  
element(by.css('select[formcontrolname="brandName"] > option[ng-reflect-value="APPLE"]')).click();

3)
element(by.xpath('//select[@formcontrolname="brandName"]/option[text()="APPLE"]')).click();
```

Comment: Tried as above but displaying error Message as: 
**Message: Failed:No element found using locator: By(css selector, select[formcontrolname="brandName"] > option[ng-reflect-value="APPLE"])**

**Message: Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //select[@formcontrolname="brandName"]/option[text()="APPLE"]) **

**Message: Failed:
element(by.cssContainingText('select[formcontrolname="brandName"] > option', 'APPLE')).click()**